Facebook Graph API for publishing a Post
I am working on an app that helps in publishing the post on different platforms in a single go. User has to write about their post and add pictures if they want and then select the social media they want to post on like they can select facebook and instagram or facebook,Instagram and X and when the click the button based on the selection post should be publish on there social media account.
What Problem I am facing?
I am able to create a button that helps user to login to facebook and thats working perfectly. But when it comes to publishing a post it doesn't work. Please let me know what I can do to make that code run??
Here is the code snippet for publishing post to facebook.
private void postToFacebook(String token, String msg) {
        String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/me/feed";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Handle success
                        Log.d("FBResponse", response);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Post Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Handle error
                Log.e("FBError", error.toString());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to Post: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("message", msg);
                params.put("access_token", token);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

This is the error I am getting when I am trying to publish a post.
2024-09-07 07:34:41.246  5642-5734  Volley                  com.example.post                     E  [83] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 403 for https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/me/feed
2024-09-07 07:34:41.416   790-790   StatusBarIconController com.android.systemui                 D  ignoring old pipeline callbacks, because the new mobile icons are enabled
2024-09-07 07:34:41.484  5642-5734  Volley                  com.example.post                     E  [83] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 403 for https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/me/feed
2024-09-07 07:34:41.486  5642-5642  FBError                 com.example.post                     E  com.android.volley.AuthFailureError

